# Is there any way to instantiate an anonymous inner class?

Tags: java, inner-classes

Is there any way to access the method of an anonymous class from main method?
If so, what is the syntax for accessing such a method?

Comment: care to illustrate what code you are having trouble with?

Comment: check this link may be you will get some idea:http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/inner-class-java/

Comment: @Soorapadman link has a valid answer for you

Comment: Thanks for the link , but why it is not possible to access a method  of anonymous class that is not overridden the method of outer class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If You have at least one instance (object) of anonymous class, at first seems yes:

```
class Demo {
   void show() {
      System.out.println("i am in show method of super class");
   }
}
public class Flavor1Demo {

   //  An anonymous class with Demo as base class
   static Demo d2 = new Demo() {
       void show() {
           super.show();
           System.out.println("i am in Flavor1Demo class");
       }
   };
   public static void main(String[] args){
       d2.show();
       try {
        Demo v = d2.getClass().newInstance();
        System.out.println("Object created"+v.getClass().getTypeName()); // Canonical is null
    } catch (InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
   }
}
```

I'm surprised, anonymous cls seems be static type, don't need hidden reference to parent? Seems no.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Demo {
   void show() {
      System.out.println("i am in show method of super class");
   }
}
class Flavor1Demo {

   //  An anonymous class with Demo as base class
   static Demo d = new Demo() {
       void show() {
           super.show();
           System.out.println("i am in Flavor1Demo class");
       }
   };
   public static void main(String[] args){
       d.show();
   }
}
```

Comment: these are few important word is this area: anonymous class, inner class, static class, must be precise. You write different question in Topic, different in body

Answer (score 0):

***Anonymous classes*** are instantiated at the same time you need them. They don't have their names. If you have coded with Swing or applets then there are `ActionListeners or EventHandlers` that are actually instantiated anonymoysly